# new Function("JS string") unavoidable?

Tags: javascript, node.js, security, eval

On an API call from online stores to our Rails app, I need to send strings of HTML, CSS and JS to build a modal on their frontend. If the HTML and CSS are not an issue, the JS looks problematic as I am willing to use new Function ("js script in string") to add JS to my modal.

I read everywhere that new Function(), like eval(), is not secure at all but I cannot see any other way to do it.

To give more context, I am subject to two constraints

- I have hundreds of templates saved in my DB (template_id, html, css, js) that can be called by each store
- I need to access functions/modules that have been declared before like in the example below

```
import moduleX from 'moduleX'

const functionX = () => { something() }

const runJS = (js_string) => {
  const specificJS = new Function('moduleX', 'functionX', js_string)
  specificJS(moduleX, functionX)
}

const buildPopup = (popup_data) => {
  insertHtml(popup_data.html)
  insertCss(popup_data.css)
  runJS(popup_data.js)
}
```

Is there a more secure way to do it?

Comment: If you've set it up to only work by running arbitrary JS then you cannot easily change it to not run arbitrary JS. But that's a design problem. If you instead send some instructions for *what* to run they can be interpreted on the frontend and an appropriate *safe* program constructed on the fly. Yet that's not really what you've done, hence the problem of converting to that approach.

Comment: You could have an HTTP API to your server to fetch the JavaScript code for a template, and use the URL for a template script in a `<script>` tag. I agree with VLAZ however, I think this is a situation that calls for an architectural re-think.

Comment: "*I read everywhere that new Function(), like eval(), is not secure at all*" - nope. You're missing a crucial constraint there: running arbitrary **untrusted** scripts is not secure. Otherwise it's no different than executing code from `<script>`s (from a security viewpoint). And it has exactly the same security concerns as embedding arbitrary untrusted html snippets in your page. So: do you trust all the code snippets in your database (and the people who manage them)? If yes, then there's no security issue.